# Getting 405 Method Not Allowed while using POST method in bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I am developing one simple code for force download now problem is that i'm not getting any error in GET method but getting error "405 Method Not Allowed" in post method request. My code for GET method.

```
@route('/down/<filename:path>',method=['GET', 'POST'])
    def home(filename):
        key = request.get.GET('key')
        if key == "tCJVNTh21nEJSekuQesM2A":        
            return static_file(filename, root='/home/azoi/tmp/bottle/down/', download=filename)
        else:
    return "File Not Found"
```

When i request with key it is returning me file for download when it is get method
http://mydomain.com/down/xyz.pdf?key=tCJVNTh21nEJSekuQesM2A

Now i used another code for handling POST methods

```
@route('/down/<filename:path>',method=['GET', 'POST'])
    def home(filename):
        key = request.body.readline()
        if key == "tCJVNTh21nEJSekuQesM2A":        
            return static_file(filename, root='/home/azoi/tmp/bottle/down/', download=filename)
        else:
            return "File Not Found"
```

Now by using this code i cannot handle post method i.e. i am getting 405 Method Not Allowed error from server.

Any solution for this ?

Comment: How do you launch the request?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Router takes only one method in `method` parameter, not list of methods. Use several `@route` decorators instead:

```
@route('/down/<filename:path>', method='GET')
@route('/down/<filename:path>', method='POST')
def home(filename):
    pass
```

Check documentation for more information: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/routing.html#routing-order

**UPDATE**

Recent Bottle version allows to specify list of methods: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Bottle.route

Comment: Actually, recent versions of Bottle allow lists of methods: [**method** – HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, ...) or a list of methods to listen to. (default: GET)](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Bottle.route)

Comment: Thank you for update, @vaultah, will update an answer.